# How to get area of convex hull of 2D points using Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I'm new to boost, and everything I try results in screens full of compiler errors.  Here's my latest attempt:

```
#include <boost/geometry/algorithm/convex_hull.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithm/area.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOOST_TUPLE_CS(cs::cartesian)

double getHullArea(std::vector<double> x, std::vector<double> y) {
  typedef boost::tuple<double,double> point;
  typedef bg::model::multi_point<point> points;
  points p;
  for (size_t i=0; i<x.size(); i++) {
    bg::append(p, point(x[i],y[i]));
  }
  bg::model::polygon hull;
  bg::convex_hull(p, hull);
  return bg::area(hull);
}
```

I know there are some clever things that avoid the multipoint, but I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong with this basic approach.  The errors are at the `convex_hull` call, possibly related to how I defined *hull*.

EDIT:  Added includes I was using when getting the errors.

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: Nothing that makes sense to me or that points to anything specific.  It goes back into the boost hpp files.  Example: "No type named 'point_type' in 'struct::boost::geometry::strategy::not_implemented".  It's on another machine so I can't just paste it all in.

Comment: it may not make sense to you but error messages shouldn't be ignored, please include them in the question

Comment: The code is on a non networked machine.  I would paste them if I could.  The bottom line errors point to convex_hull_concept.hpp, lines 42, 45, and 48.  They all end in "not implemented" as my previous comment.

Comment: no errors when I add a template parameter for `polygon`: https://godbolt.org/z/gNGc_5. You need to include the errors, otherwise we cannot know what errors you get

Comment: I modified my code to show the includes I was using.  I discovered that replacing the individual includes for convex_hull and area with a global include of ..geometry.hpp cleared up my problem.  Thanks all for helping.

Comment: There is no header called `<boost/geometry/algorithm/complex_hull.hpp>` it is `convex_hull`

Comment: Fixed.  All this is copied over my shoulder from another box.

Comment: why fix it in the question? Is this the code that produces an error?

Comment: Yes, the code up there produces the error on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the includes.  `<boost/geometry.hhp>` must be included.  This works:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOOST_TUPLE_CS(cs::cartesian)

double getHullArea(std::vector<double> x, std::vector<double> y) {
  typedef boost::tuple<double,double> point;
  typedef bg::model::multi_point<point> points;
  points p;
  for (size_t i=0; i<x.size(); i++) {
    bg::append(p, point(x[i],y[i]));
  }
  bg::model::polygon hull;
  bg::convex_hull(p, hull);
  return bg::area(hull);
}
```